# android BootCompletedReceiver not fire

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I have an android application with this config on Manifest :

```
    <receiver android:name="ir.hamgam.fion.ec.mobile.services.BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and in my Receiver i have this :

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.w("boot_broadcast_poc", "starting service...");
            APKUpdateReceiver.setAlarm(context);
            DataReceiver.setAlarm(context);
            NotificationUpdateReceiver.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

when application starts and boot completed but not fire inside method onreceive,give me hint please.

Comment: I assume you have the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` set in the manifest?

Comment: yes i add it to my manifest but not working ...

Comment: Are you sure the `<receiver>` and `<uses-permission>` elements are in the correct places in the manifest? Have you launched your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state?

Comment: yes i didi it truly

Comment: in my android application i need to mechanism that i download some file from web server forever application running in during of time, is BroadcastReceiver is ok for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do as below, it works fine. 
I put a Toast inside your receiver to be notified about the receiver is called -

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Log.w("boot_broadcast_poc", "starting service...");
        Toast.makeText(context, "HElllllooooooo ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            APKUpdateReceiver.setAlarm(context);
//            DataReceiver.setAlarm(context);
//            NotificationUpdateReceiver.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Now change the manifest as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shajib.stackoverflow">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```